# Using nested case statements in Snowflake/SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table which looks like this, lets call it data_set

| ID | Can_Afford | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Car | Neg |
| 2 | Bus | Pos |
| 3 | Bike | Other |

Now I am trying to create a table to define speed limits as below

```
with city_speed_limits(Name,Capacity,Owner,Toll_Price,Max_Speed) as (
    select * from values 
        ('Bus','Heavy','City',null,'50 kmph'),
        ('Car','Light','Private','Toll','60 kmph'),
        ('Bike','Light','Private',null,null)
                              
)
```

After this, I am now trying to write a query which would give this as output

| ID | Name | Owner | Speed | Affordability |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Car | Private | 60 kpmh | NEGATIVE |
| 2 | Bus | City | 50 kmph | POSITIVE |
| 3 | Bike | Private | null | UNKNOWN |

**I am unable to figure out the nested case statement part here**

My Query so far

```
with city_speed_limits(Name,Capacity,Owner,Toll_Price,Max_Speed) as (
    select * from values 
        ('Bus','Heavy','City',null,'50 kmph'),
        ('Car','Light','Private','Toll','60 kmph'),
        ('Bike','Light','Private',null,null)
            
)
select 
    a.ID as ID, 
    b.Name as Name,
    b.Owner as Owner,
    b.Max_Speed as Speed,
    iff(b.Max_Speed is not null, 'UNKNOWN', 'KNOWN')
    CASE 
        WHEN b.Name in ('Bus','Car') then
            CASE 
                WHEN a.Description = 'Neg' then 'NEGATIVE'
                WHEN a.Description = 'Pos' then 'POSITIVE'
                WHEN a.Description = 'Other' then 'UNKNOWN'
            END
    END as Affordability
from data_set a
cross join city_speed_limits b
```

My affordability is based on two conditions, if the speed is null then UNKNOWN and if it is specified in my base table as pos,neg or other then I am expanding the shortform to POSITIVE, NEGATIVE or UKNOWN

Answer (score 0):

so if you put a comma after your `IFF`

```
iff(b.Max_Speed is not null, 'UNKNOWN', 'KNOWN'),
```

your code runs but gives:

[image]

you should swap from a cross join to a left join and add an ON clause

like:

```
from data_set a
left join city_speed_limits b
    on a.Can_Afford = b.name
```

and then you can drop the IFF, and flip the logic, when the LEFT join fails, output UNKNOWN else, lookup those three values, of which you could skip the `Other` and default to UNKNOWN again, thus like so:

```
with data_set(ID, Can_Afford,Description) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 'Car', 'Neg'),
        (2, 'Bus', 'Pos'),
        (3, 'Bike', 'Other')
), city_speed_limits(Name,Capacity,Owner,Toll_Price,Max_Speed) as (
    select * from values 
        ('Bus','Heavy','City',null,'50 kmph'),
        ('Car','Light','Private','Toll','60 kmph'),
        ('Bike','Light','Private',null,null)    
)
select 
    a.ID as ID, 
    b.Name as Name,
    b.Owner as Owner,
    b.Max_Speed as Speed,
    CASE 
        WHEN b.name is null then 'UNKNOWN'
        ELSE 
            CASE 
                WHEN a.Description = 'Neg' then 'NEGATIVE'
                WHEN a.Description = 'Pos' then 'POSITIVE'
                ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
            END
    END as Affordability
from data_set a
left join city_speed_limits b
    on a.Can_Afford = b.name
```

| ID | NAME | OWNER | SPEED | AFFORDABILITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Car | Private | 60 kmph | NEGATIVE |
| 2 | Bus | City |  | 50 kmph |
| 3 | Bike |  | Private | UNKNOWN |

Cleaner would be to use [DECODE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/decode) for that second CASE:

```
DECODE(a.Description, 'Neg', 'NEGATIVE', 'Pos', 'POSITIVE', 'UNKNOWN')
```

Thus you could move back to a IFF

```
    IFF(b.name is null,
        'UNKNOWN',
        DECODE(a.Description, 'Neg', 'NEGATIVE', 'Pos', 'POSITIVE', 'UNKNOWN') 
    ) as Affordability
```

NVL2 can also be used instead of the IFF:

```
    NVL2(b.name, 
        DECODE(a.Description, 'Neg', 'NEGATIVE', 'Pos', 'POSITIVE', 'UNKNOWN'),
        'UNKNOWN'
    ) as Affordability
```

I feel like there might be some cute way to trash `a.Description` to null, when `b.name` is null, but otherwise leave it alone, then you could use DECODE to do all the work. But that is escaping me.